# CS:GO MM Official Servers Periodically HIGH Delay

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

The last two weeks that I have been playing CS:GO MM on official servers, it happened on ALL matches, except maybe one or two, that on whole game, most or even all players had really high ping, making the game unplayable, due to the high delay and lag.

Is this a known problem to Steam? Is it only CS:GO servers? Do users on other games experience the same thing? What is going on with their servers? I didn't find any official announcement or something.

Comment: BTT: It is a known problem and there are often server lags which affect every player. That you had them every time is maybe misfortune, too. Probably you play mostly to the main times (in the evening | on weekends).

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 not only afternoons first of all, second of all its only me i know of other people and streamers having same problems..... It cant be that this lag is coming just from too many people playing, i am telling you no way. Plus even if it could that one, it wouldnt that much (from Mirage CT spawn to go to t-ramp you need 30+ seconds)......

Comment: Yes but when all players in the match receive the increasing ping it can only be the server's fault and you can nothing do except reporting the server and thus generating a (perhabs ?) better future.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2mdsya/mm_is_basically_unplayable_right_now/ Here you can read that it seem to be Valve servers in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a widely known current issue, and Valve has been attempting to fix it. (Alas, to no avail so far.)
There's a notice by Valve themselves on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/4n7i1o/matchmaking_server_issues/#notice), which includes some pointers on helping them pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://steamstat.us/) website to help you determine if the servers are under heavy load.

More likely though, your game is looking for any MM game it can find. Limit the max acceptable ping to something appropriate:

> mm_dedicated_search_maxping 70

Although if your internet is on the low end, you might need to increase this to 100 or 150. What the command does is match you in servers where your ping will be less than the number. This in theory should make for smoother experience and hopefully less lag.

Comment: I have done all these you say since i started playing... My internet speed is 50mgps download 4,5 mgps upload. Plus i am telling you that i know its not me having the problem because i know many people and streamers that have the same problem every time. FYI i know of that site man, i had been looking at it occasionally and i have seen that there are many drops (goes down around 70% from 98+) of the system every day

Comment: Its nto the players fault because also when we go in game and we are on warm up its all good, everyone has less than 50 ping after the 2-3 round then everybody gets 250+... it has to be the stupid servers